# Error Code: 38 DB::Exception: Cannot parse date: value is too short: Cannot parse Date from String:while executing 'FUNCTION toDate()'

Tags: clickhouse

When I am using this query:

```sql
SELECT
    store_id,
    toDate(concat(year, '-', month, '-', day)) AS date,
    COUNTDistinct(session_id) AS visits
FROM s3data.visits_parquet_improved
WHERE isNotNull(session_id) AND ((toDate(concat(year, '-', month, '-', day)) >= toDate('2021-06-23')) AND (toDate(concat(year, '-', month, '-', day)) <= toDate('2021-06-24')))
GROUP BY
    store_id,
    year,
    month,
    day
ORDER BY
    year ASC,
    month ASC,
    day ASC
```

return this error:

```
Received exception from server (version 21.7.4):
Code: 38. DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000. DB::Exception: Cannot parse date: 
value is too short: Cannot parse Date from String: while executing 
'FUNCTION toDate(concat(year, '-', month, '-', day) :: 9) -> toDate(concat(year, '-', month, '-', day)) Date : 5'.
```

Does someone know why and how to fix it?

Comment: The error message tells you exactly why - the value you're trying to parse into a date is too short. Either the year, month or day value you're sending (which you don't include in your post) isn't correct.

Comment: what is the minimal **year** value in your dataset?

Comment: @KenWhite the values for year, month and day are (for example) 2021, 5, 31

Answer (score 2):

```
select toDate('');
DB::Exception: Cannot parse date: value is too short: Cannot parse Date from String: While processing toDate('').


:) select toDateOrZero('');

┌─toDateOrZero('')─┐
│       1970-01-01 │
└──────────────────┘


:) SELECT toDateOrNull('')

┌─toDateOrNull('')─┐
│             ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │
└──────────────────┘


:) SELECT toDate(parseDateTimeBestEffortOrNull('20210601'))

┌─toDate(parseDateTimeBestEffortOrNull('20210601'))─┐
│                                        2021-06-01 │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```